# Finding duplicates document values in a MongoDB collection based on 2 fields

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm a bit stumped here and I'm hoping to find some guidance on the following.

I want to find duplicate documents in a collection, based on two field values using the MongoDB official library for PHP (PHP version 8, mongodb version 1.15.0 on composer).

The duplicate values I'm interested in is `section-1` and `auto-generated-number`.
If I have duplicates, I want to be able to get a count of how many there are.

Here's what I've got so far:

`$form['approvedrenumberedfield']` is being set as a string value that equals `section-1`.

```
    $aggregate = [
      array(
        '$project' => array(
            "_id" => 0,
            "name" => '$_id',
            "count" => 1,
        ),
      ),
      array(
        '$group' => array(
          "_id" => '$' . $form['approvedrenumberedfield'],
          'count' => array('$sum' => 1),
        ),
      ),
      array(
          '$match' => array(
              $form['approvedrenumberedfield'] => '$' . $form['approvedrenumberedfield'],
              'auto-generated-number' => '$auto-generated-number',
              'count' => array('$gt' => 1),
          )
      )
    ];
```

The concept of aggregation makes sense to me but I think I'm running into a syntax issue with the code. I've searched online for some assistance on writing aggregation for Mongo in PHP so I've tried different approaches, so apologies if this is an absolute monstrosity!

I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [$project] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => 0
                    [name] => $_id
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [$group] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => $section-1
                    [count] => Array
                        (
                            [$sum] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [$match] => Array
                (
                    [section-1] => $section-1
                    [auto-generated-number] => $auto-generated-number
                    [count] => Array
                        (
                            [$gt] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And I get the following output from a dump of the mongo object after calling `aggregate` on the `entries` collection.

```
MongoDB\Driver\Cursor Object
(
    [database] => AHSR
    [collection] => 
    [query] => 
    [command] => MongoDB\Driver\Command Object
        (
            [command] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [aggregate] => entries
                    [pipeline] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$project] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_id] => 0
                                            [name] => $_id
                                            [count] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$group] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_id] => $section-1
                                            [count] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [$sum] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$match] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [section-1] => $section-1
                                            [auto-generated-number] => $auto-generated-number
                                            [count] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [$gt] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [cursor] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [readPreference] => MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference Object
        (
            [mode] => primary
        )

    [session] => MongoDB\Driver\Session Object
        (
            [logicalSessionId] => Array
                (
                    [id] => MongoDB\BSON\Binary Object
                        (
                            [data] => �b�p�!KZ��$��&�
                            [type] => 4
                        )

                )

            [clusterTime] => 
            [causalConsistency] => 1
            [snapshot] => 
            [operationTime] => 
            [server] => 
            [dirty] => 
            [inTransaction] => 
            [transactionState] => none
            [transactionOptions] => 
        )

    [isDead] => 
    [currentIndex] => 0
    [currentDocument] => 
    [server] => MongoDB\Driver\Server Object
        (
            [host] => localhost
            [port] => 27017
            [type] => 1
            [is_primary] => 
            [is_secondary] => 
            [is_arbiter] => 
            [is_hidden] => 
            [is_passive] => 
            [last_hello_response] => Array
                (
                    [helloOk] => 1
                    [isWritablePrimary] => 1
                    [topologyVersion] => Array
                        (
                            [processId] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                                (
                                    [oid] => 641a44d3995deb7113b70a85
                                )

                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                    [maxBsonObjectSize] => 16777216
                    [maxMessageSizeBytes] => 48000000
                    [maxWriteBatchSize] => 100000
                    [localTime] => MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object
                        (
                            [milliseconds] => 1680305454006
                        )

                    [logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes] => 30
                    [connectionId] => 19
                    [minWireVersion] => 0
                    [maxWireVersion] => 13
                    [readOnly] => 
                    [saslSupportedMechs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SCRAM-SHA-1
                            [1] => SCRAM-SHA-256
                        )

                    [ok] => 1
                )

            [round_trip_time] => 0
        )
```

One last note, I can confirm that I have documents in my collection that have these duplicate fields.

Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things causing problems here.

In a `$project` stage, including a field implicitly excludes all other fields except _id.  In the example you show, _id is explicitly excluded.

The documents that are passed along the aggregation pipeline after this $project stage will have only 2 fields: 'name' and 'count'.  Since 'count' is specified as `1`, the count field will only be present if it was already present in the source documents.

```
Array
    (
            [$project] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => 0
                    [name] => $_id
                    [count] => 1
                )
    )
```

Example: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/maF6T4_CP4g)

This stage will group the documents by the 'section-1' field.  Because the 'section-1' field was removed by the previous $project, all documents now have the same value for that field (null), so this puts all documents into the same group, and provides a count.  The only document passed along by this stage will have `_id` null, and a count of the total number of documents.

Example: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QhqMFOFRCnq)

With a $match stage the query is expected to use the MongoDB query language(MQL).  According to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#-match--aggregation-) $match does not accept raw aggregation expressions.

The `$fieldname` notation is an aggregation expression and as such is not supported in $match without using [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#-expr).

The expression `'$auto-generated-number'` evaluates to the value currently held by the field `auto-generated-number`.  It is not possible for a field to have any other value than the value it currents holds, so this expression would be a tautology if it were permitted in the MQL:

```
 'auto-generated-number' => '$auto-generated-number',
```

If we rewrite that expressions using $expr it might look something like:

```
Array(
   "$expr" => Array(
        "$eq" => Array(
              "$auto-generated-number",
              "$auto-generated-number"
         )
   )
)
```

Which would then simply match everything, example: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fSFlYT9wXhQ)

I suspect what you intended was to retrieve a list of duplicate values, each with a list of the document _ids that were duplicated.  That could be accomplished with a pipeline such as:

```
Array(
 '$group' => Array(
      '_id' => Array(
        'section-1' => '$section-1',
        'auto-generated-number' => '$auto-generated-number'
      ),  
      'count' => Array( '$sum' => 1 )
  ),
  '$match' => Array(
      'count' => Array( '$gt' => 1 ) 
       
  ),
)
```

Example: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/og7CYk-w69I)